# Building Curl from source not creating libcurl.so artifact

Tags: curl, libcurl

Greetings i am building curl from source on MacOs and seems like whatever i do i am not able to generate the libcurl.so file needed for my application ,

steps that i followed

- clone curl from git
- ran ./configure --with-openssl=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3 --prefix=/Users/foo/AlexaWorkspace/curl2.0/out1
- ran make
- ran make install

Can someone more experience can me please have a look and tell me what i am missing or doing incorrect.

Please note that i have also tried setting options like --enable-shared and --enable-static during configure but when i navigate to the out dir i only see libcurl.dylib as shown [image: pic attached]
out1 dir [image: screenshots]

```
foo@bcd074b280e3 curl % ./configure --with-openssl=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3 --prefix=/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1 
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable debug build options... no
checking whether to enable compiler optimizer... (assumed) yes
checking whether to enable strict compiler warnings... no
checking whether to enable compiler warnings as errors... no
checking whether to enable curl debug memory tracking... no
checking whether to enable hiding of library internal symbols... yes
checking whether to enable c-ares for DNS lookups... no
checking whether to disable dependency on -lrt... (assumed no)
checking whether to enable ECH support... no
checking for path separator... :
checking for sed... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep... /usr/bin/grep
checking that grep -E works... yes
checking for ar... /usr/bin/ar
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for stdatomic.h... yes
checking if _Atomic is available... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /usr/bin/sed
checking for code coverage support... no
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a race-free mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking curl version... 7.87.1-DEV
checking for httpd... /usr/sbin/httpd
checking for apachectl... /usr/sbin/apachectl
checking for apxs... no
configure: apxs not in PATH, httpd tests disabled
checking for apxs... no
checking for caddy... no
checking build system type... aarch64-apple-darwin22.3.0
checking host system type... aarch64-apple-darwin22.3.0
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... (cached) /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking if OS is AIX (to define _ALL_SOURCE)... no
checking if _THREAD_SAFE is already defined... no
checking if _THREAD_SAFE is actually needed... no
checking if _THREAD_SAFE is onwards defined... no
checking if _REENTRANT is already defined... no
checking if _REENTRANT is actually needed... no
checking if _REENTRANT is onwards defined... no
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /usr/bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 786432
checking how to convert aarch64-apple-darwin22.3.0 file names to aarch64-apple-darwin22.3.0 format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert aarch64-apple-darwin22.3.0 file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for file... file
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for archiver @FILE support... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for lipo... lipo
checking for otool... otool
checking for otool64... no
checking for -single_module linker flag... yes
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking for -force_load linker flag... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fno-common -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fno-common -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin22.3.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries with -version-info... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries with -no-undefined... no
checking whether to build shared libraries with -mimpure-text... no
checking whether to build shared libraries with PIC... yes
checking whether to build static libraries with PIC... no
checking whether to build shared libraries only... no
checking whether to build static libraries only... no
...
configure: Configured to build curl/libcurl:

  Host setup:       aarch64-apple-darwin22.3.0
  Install prefix:   /Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1
  Compiler:         gcc
   CFLAGS:          -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -O2 -Wno-system-headers
   CPPFLAGS:        -isystem /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.7/include -DOPENSSL_SUPPRESS_DEPRECATED -isystem /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libidn2/2.3.4_1/include -isystem /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libnghttp2/1.51.0/include
   LDFLAGS:         -framework CoreFoundation -framework SystemConfiguration -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.7/lib -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libidn2/2.3.4_1/lib -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libnghttp2/1.51.0/lib
   LIBS:            -lnghttp2 -lidn2 -lssl -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lldap -lz

  curl version:     7.87.1-DEV
  SSL:              enabled (OpenSSL v3+)
  SSH:              no      (--with-{libssh,libssh2})
  zlib:             enabled
  brotli:           no      (--with-brotli)
  zstd:             no      (--with-zstd)
  GSS-API:          no      (--with-gssapi)
  GSASL:            no      (libgsasl not found)
  TLS-SRP:          enabled
  resolver:         POSIX threaded
  IPv6:             enabled
  Unix sockets:     enabled
  IDN:              enabled (libidn2)
  Build libcurl:    Shared=yes, Static=yes
  Built-in manual:  no      (--enable-manual)
  --libcurl option: enabled (--disable-libcurl-option)
  Verbose errors:   enabled (--disable-verbose)
  Code coverage:    disabled
  SSPI:             no      (--enable-sspi)
  ca cert bundle:   /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  ca cert path:     no
  ca fallback:      no
  LDAP:             enabled (OpenLDAP)
  LDAPS:            enabled
  RTSP:             enabled
  RTMP:             no      (--with-librtmp)
  PSL:              no      (libpsl not found)
  Alt-svc:          enabled (--disable-alt-svc)
  Headers API:      enabled (--disable-headers-api)
  HSTS:             enabled (--disable-hsts)
  HTTP1:            enabled (internal)
  HTTP2:            enabled (nghttp2)
  HTTP3:            no      (--with-ngtcp2, --with-quiche --with-msh3)
  ECH:              no      (--enable-ech)
  WebSockets:       no      (--enable-websockets)
  Protocols:        DICT FILE FTP FTPS GOPHER GOPHERS HTTP HTTPS IMAP IMAPS LDAP LDAPS MQTT POP3 POP3S RTSP SMB SMBS SMTP SMTPS TELNET TFTP
  Features:         AsynchDNS HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets alt-svc libz threadsafe

foo@bcd074b280e3 curl % make
Making all in lib
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  all-am
  CC       libcurl_la-altsvc.lo
  CC       libcurl_la-amigaos.lo
  CC       libcurl_la-asyn-ares.lo
  CC       libcurl_la-asyn-thread.lo
  CC       libcurl_la-base64.lo
  CC       libcurl_la-bufref.lo
  CC       libcurl_la-c-hyper.lo
  CC       libcurl_la-cf-http.lo
  CC       libcurl_la-cf-socket.lo
  CC       libcurl_la-cfilters.lo
  CC       libcurl_la-conncache.lo
  CC       libcurl_la-connect.lo
  CC       libcurl_la-content_encoding.lo
  CC       libcurl_la-cookie.lo
  CC       libcurl_la-curl_addrinfo.lo
  CC       libcurl_la-curl_des.lo
  CC       libcurl_la-curl_endian.lo
  CC       libcurl_la-curl_fnmatch.lo
  CC       libcurl_la-curl_get_line.lo
  CC       libcurl_la-curl_gethostname.lo
  CC       libcurl_la-curl_gssapi.lo
  CC       libcurl_la-curl_log.lo
  CC       libcurl_la-curl_memrchr.lo
  CC       libcurl_la-curl_multibyte.lo
  CC       libcurl_la-curl_ntlm_core.lo
  ...
  CC       vssh/libcurl_la-wolfssh.lo
  CCLD     libcurl.la
ld: warning: -undefined dynamic_lookup may not work with chained fixups
ld: warning: cannot export hidden symbol _curl_jmpenv from .libs/libcurl_la-hostip.o
Making all in src
Making all in ../docs
Making all in .
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
Making all in cmdline-opts
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
  CC       slist_wc.o
  CC       tool_binmode.o
  CC       tool_bname.o
  ...
  CC       ../lib/dynbuf.o
  CCLD     curl
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.

foo@bcd074b280e3 curl % make install
Making install in lib
 .././install-sh -c -d '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/lib'
 /bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libcurl.la '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libcurl.4.dylib /Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
libtool: install: (cd /Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/lib && { ln -s -f libcurl.4.dylib libcurl.dylib || { rm -f libcurl.dylib && ln -s libcurl.4.dylib libcurl.dylib; }; })
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libcurl.lai /Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/lib/libcurl.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libcurl.a /Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/lib/libcurl.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/lib/libcurl.a
libtool: install: ranlib /Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/lib/libcurl.a
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in src
Making install in ../docs
Making install in .
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 .././install-sh -c -d '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/share/man/man1'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 curl-config.1 /Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/curl/docs/curl.1 '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/share/man/man1'
Making install in cmdline-opts
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
 .././install-sh -c -d '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/bin'
  /bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c curl '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/bin'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/curl /Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/bin/curl
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
 ./install-sh -c -d '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/bin'
 /usr/bin/install -c curl-config '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/bin'
 ./install-sh -c -d '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/lib/pkgconfig'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libcurl.pc '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/lib/pkgconfig'
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-data-hook
(cd include && /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make install)
Making install in curl
make[6]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 ../.././install-sh -c -d '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/include/curl'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 curl.h curlver.h easy.h mprintf.h stdcheaders.h multi.h typecheck-gcc.h system.h urlapi.h options.h header.h websockets.h '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/include/curl'
make[6]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[6]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
(cd docs && /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make install)
Making install in .
make[6]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 .././install-sh -c -d '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/share/man/man1'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 curl-config.1 /Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/curl/docs/curl.1 '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/share/man/man1'
Making install in cmdline-opts
make[6]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[6]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
(cd docs/libcurl && /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make install)
Making install in opts
make[6]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 ../../.././install-sh -c -d '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/share/man/man3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 CURLINFO_ACTIVESOCKET.3 CURLINFO_APPCONNECT_TIME.3 CURLINFO_APPCONNECT_TIME_T.3 CURLINFO_CAINFO.3 CURLINFO_CAPATH.3 CURLINFO_CERTINFO.3 CURLINFO_CONDITION_UNMET.3 CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME.3 CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME_T.3 CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD.3 CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD_T.3 CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_UPLOAD.3 CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_UPLOAD_T.3 CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE.3 CURLINFO_COOKIELIST.3 CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_METHOD.3 CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL.3 CURLINFO_FILETIME.3 CURLINFO_FILETIME_T.3 CURLINFO_FTP_ENTRY_PATH.3 CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE.3 CURLINFO_HTTP_CONNECTCODE.3 CURLINFO_HTTP_VERSION.3 CURLINFO_HTTPAUTH_AVAIL.3 CURLINFO_LASTSOCKET.3 CURLINFO_LOCAL_IP.3 CURLINFO_LOCAL_PORT.3 CURLINFO_NAMELOOKUP_TIME.3 CURLINFO_NAMELOOKUP_TIME_T.3 CURLINFO_NUM_CONNECTS.3 CURLINFO_OS_ERRNO.3 CURLINFO_PRETRANSFER_TIME.3 CURLINFO_PRETRANSFER_TIME_T.3 CURLINFO_PRIMARY_IP.3 CURLINFO_PRIMARY_PORT.3 CURLINFO_PRIVATE.3 CURLINFO_PROTOCOL.3 CURLINFO_PROXY_ERROR.3 CURLINFO_PROXY_SSL_VERIFYRESULT.3 CURLINFO_PROXYAUTH_AVAIL.3 '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/share/man/man3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 CURLINFO_REDIRECT_COUNT.3 CURLINFO_REDIRECT_TIME.3 CURLINFO_REDIRECT_TIME_T.3 CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL.3 CURLINFO_REFERER.3 CURLINFO_REQUEST_SIZE.3 CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE.3 CURLINFO_RETRY_AFTER.3 CURLINFO_RTSP_CLIENT_CSEQ.3 CURLINFO_RTSP_CSEQ_RECV.3 CURLINFO_RTSP_SERVER_CSEQ.3 CURLINFO_RTSP_SESSION_ID.3 CURLINFO_SCHEME.3 CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD.3 CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD_T.3 CURLINFO_SIZE_UPLOAD.3 CURLINFO_SIZE_UPLOAD_T.3 CURLINFO_SPEED_DOWNLOAD.3 CURLINFO_SPEED_DOWNLOAD_T.3 CURLINFO_SPEED_UPLOAD.3 CURLINFO_SPEED_UPLOAD_T.3 CURLINFO_SSL_ENGINES.3 CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT.3 CURLINFO_STARTTRANSFER_TIME.3 CURLINFO_STARTTRANSFER_TIME_T.3 CURLINFO_TLS_SESSION.3 CURLINFO_TLS_SSL_PTR.3 CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME.3 CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME_T.3 CURLMOPT_CHUNK_LENGTH_PENALTY_SIZE.3 CURLMOPT_CONTENT_LENGTH_PENALTY_SIZE.3 CURLMOPT_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS.3 CURLMOPT_MAX_HOST_CONNECTIONS.3 CURLMOPT_MAX_PIPELINE_LENGTH.3 CURLMOPT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS.3 CURLMOPT_MAXCONNECTS.3 CURLMOPT_PIPELINING.3 CURLMOPT_PIPELINING_SERVER_BL.3 CURLMOPT_PIPELINING_SITE_BL.3 CURLMOPT_PUSHDATA.3 '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/share/man/man3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 CURLMOPT_PUSHFUNCTION.3 CURLMOPT_SOCKETDATA.3 CURLMOPT_SOCKETFUNCTION.3 CURLMOPT_TIMERDATA.3 CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_ABSTRACT_UNIX_SOCKET.3 CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING.3 CURLOPT_ACCEPTTIMEOUT_MS.3 CURLOPT_ADDRESS_SCOPE.3 CURLOPT_ALTSVC.3 CURLOPT_ALTSVC_CTRL.3 CURLOPT_APPEND.3 CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER.3 CURLOPT_AWS_SIGV4.3 CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE.3 CURLOPT_CAINFO.3 CURLOPT_CAINFO_BLOB.3 CURLOPT_CAPATH.3 CURLOPT_CA_CACHE_TIMEOUT.3 CURLOPT_CERTINFO.3 CURLOPT_CHUNK_BGN_FUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_CHUNK_DATA.3 CURLOPT_CHUNK_END_FUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETDATA.3 CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY.3 CURLOPT_CONNECT_TO.3 CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT.3 CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS.3 CURLOPT_CONV_FROM_NETWORK_FUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_CONV_FROM_UTF8_FUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_CONV_TO_NETWORK_FUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_COOKIE.3 CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE.3 CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR.3 CURLOPT_COOKIELIST.3 CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION.3 CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS.3 CURLOPT_CRLF.3 CURLOPT_CRLFILE.3 '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/share/man/man3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 CURLOPT_CURLU.3 CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST.3 CURLOPT_DEBUGDATA.3 CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL.3 CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY.3 CURLOPT_DISALLOW_USERNAME_IN_URL.3 CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT.3 CURLOPT_DNS_INTERFACE.3 CURLOPT_DNS_LOCAL_IP4.3 CURLOPT_DNS_LOCAL_IP6.3 CURLOPT_DNS_SERVERS.3 CURLOPT_DNS_SHUFFLE_ADDRESSES.3 CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE.3 CURLOPT_DOH_SSL_VERIFYHOST.3 CURLOPT_DOH_SSL_VERIFYPEER.3 CURLOPT_DOH_SSL_VERIFYSTATUS.3 CURLOPT_DOH_URL.3 CURLOPT_EGDSOCKET.3 CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER.3 CURLOPT_EXPECT_100_TIMEOUT_MS.3 CURLOPT_FAILONERROR.3 CURLOPT_FILETIME.3 CURLOPT_FNMATCH_DATA.3 CURLOPT_FNMATCH_FUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.3 CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE.3 CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT.3 CURLOPT_FTP_ACCOUNT.3 CURLOPT_FTP_ALTERNATIVE_TO_USER.3 CURLOPT_FTP_CREATE_MISSING_DIRS.3 CURLOPT_FTP_FILEMETHOD.3 CURLOPT_FTP_SKIP_PASV_IP.3 CURLOPT_FTP_SSL_CCC.3 CURLOPT_FTP_USE_EPRT.3 CURLOPT_FTP_USE_EPSV.3 CURLOPT_FTP_USE_PRET.3 CURLOPT_FTPPORT.3 CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH.3 CURLOPT_GSSAPI_DELEGATION.3 '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/share/man/man3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 CURLOPT_HAPPY_EYEBALLS_TIMEOUT_MS.3 CURLOPT_HAPROXYPROTOCOL.3 CURLOPT_HEADER.3 CURLOPT_HEADERDATA.3 CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_HEADEROPT.3 CURLOPT_HSTS.3 CURLOPT_HSTS_CTRL.3 CURLOPT_HSTSREADDATA.3 CURLOPT_HSTSREADFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_HSTSWRITEDATA.3 CURLOPT_HSTSWRITEFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_HTTP09_ALLOWED.3 CURLOPT_HTTP200ALIASES.3 CURLOPT_HTTP_CONTENT_DECODING.3 CURLOPT_HTTP_TRANSFER_DECODING.3 CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION.3 CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH.3 CURLOPT_HTTPGET.3 CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.3 CURLOPT_HTTPPOST.3 CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL.3 CURLOPT_IGNORE_CONTENT_LENGTH.3 CURLOPT_INFILESIZE.3 CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE.3 CURLOPT_INTERFACE.3 CURLOPT_INTERLEAVEDATA.3 CURLOPT_INTERLEAVEFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_IOCTLDATA.3 CURLOPT_IOCTLFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE.3 CURLOPT_ISSUERCERT.3 CURLOPT_ISSUERCERT_BLOB.3 CURLOPT_KEEP_SENDING_ON_ERROR.3 CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD.3 CURLOPT_KRBLEVEL.3 CURLOPT_LOCALPORT.3 CURLOPT_LOCALPORTRANGE.3 CURLOPT_LOGIN_OPTIONS.3 CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT.3 '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/share/man/man3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME.3 CURLOPT_MAIL_AUTH.3 CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM.3 CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT.3 CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT_ALLLOWFAILS.3 CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE.3 CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE.3 CURLOPT_MAXAGE_CONN.3 CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS.3 CURLOPT_MAXFILESIZE.3 CURLOPT_MAXFILESIZE_LARGE.3 CURLOPT_MAXLIFETIME_CONN.3 CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS.3 CURLOPT_MIME_OPTIONS.3 CURLOPT_MIMEPOST.3 CURLOPT_NETRC.3 CURLOPT_NETRC_FILE.3 CURLOPT_NEW_DIRECTORY_PERMS.3 CURLOPT_NEW_FILE_PERMS.3 CURLOPT_NOBODY.3 CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS.3 CURLOPT_NOPROXY.3 CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL.3 CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETDATA.3 CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_PASSWORD.3 CURLOPT_PATH_AS_IS.3 CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY.3 CURLOPT_PIPEWAIT.3 CURLOPT_PORT.3 CURLOPT_POST.3 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.3 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE.3 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE.3 CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE.3 CURLOPT_POSTREDIR.3 CURLOPT_PRE_PROXY.3 CURLOPT_PREQUOTE.3 CURLOPT_PREREQDATA.3 CURLOPT_PREREQFUNCTION.3 '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/share/man/man3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 CURLOPT_PRIVATE.3 CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA.3 CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS.3 CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS_STR.3 CURLOPT_PROXY.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_CAINFO.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_CAINFO_BLOB.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_CAPATH.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_CRLFILE.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_ISSUERCERT.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_ISSUERCERT_BLOB.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_KEYPASSWD.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_PINNEDPUBLICKEY.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_SERVICE_NAME.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_SSL_CIPHER_LIST.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_SSL_OPTIONS.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_SSL_VERIFYHOST.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_SSL_VERIFYPEER.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_SSLCERT.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_SSLCERT_BLOB.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_SSLCERTTYPE.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_SSLKEY.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_SSLKEY_BLOB.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_SSLKEYTYPE.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_SSLVERSION.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_TLS13_CIPHERS.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_TLSAUTH_PASSWORD.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_TLSAUTH_TYPE.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_TLSAUTH_USERNAME.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_TRANSFER_MODE.3 CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH.3 CURLOPT_PROXYHEADER.3 CURLOPT_PROXYPASSWORD.3 CURLOPT_PROXYPORT.3 CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE.3 CURLOPT_PROXYUSERNAME.3 CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD.3 CURLOPT_PUT.3 CURLOPT_QUOTE.3 '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/share/man/man3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 CURLOPT_RANDOM_FILE.3 CURLOPT_RANGE.3 CURLOPT_READDATA.3 CURLOPT_READFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS.3 CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS_STR.3 CURLOPT_REFERER.3 CURLOPT_REQUEST_TARGET.3 CURLOPT_RESOLVE.3 CURLOPT_RESOLVER_START_DATA.3 CURLOPT_RESOLVER_START_FUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM.3 CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM_LARGE.3 CURLOPT_RTSP_CLIENT_CSEQ.3 CURLOPT_RTSP_REQUEST.3 CURLOPT_RTSP_SERVER_CSEQ.3 CURLOPT_RTSP_SESSION_ID.3 CURLOPT_RTSP_STREAM_URI.3 CURLOPT_RTSP_TRANSPORT.3 CURLOPT_SASL_AUTHZID.3 CURLOPT_SASL_IR.3 CURLOPT_SEEKDATA.3 CURLOPT_SEEKFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_SERVER_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT.3 CURLOPT_SERVICE_NAME.3 CURLOPT_SHARE.3 CURLOPT_SOCKOPTDATA.3 CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_SOCKS5_AUTH.3 CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_NEC.3 CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_SERVICE.3 CURLOPT_SSH_AUTH_TYPES.3 CURLOPT_SSH_COMPRESSION.3 CURLOPT_SSH_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY_MD5.3 CURLOPT_SSH_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY_SHA256.3 CURLOPT_SSH_KEYDATA.3 CURLOPT_SSH_KEYFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_SSH_KNOWNHOSTS.3 CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE.3 CURLOPT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEYFILE.3 '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/share/man/man3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST.3 CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_DATA.3 CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_FUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_SSL_EC_CURVES.3 CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_ALPN.3 CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_NPN.3 CURLOPT_SSL_FALSESTART.3 CURLOPT_SSL_OPTIONS.3 CURLOPT_SSL_SESSIONID_CACHE.3 CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST.3 CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.3 CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYSTATUS.3 CURLOPT_SSLCERT.3 CURLOPT_SSLCERT_BLOB.3 CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE.3 CURLOPT_SSLENGINE.3 CURLOPT_SSLENGINE_DEFAULT.3 CURLOPT_SSLKEY.3 CURLOPT_SSLKEY_BLOB.3 CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE.3 CURLOPT_SSLVERSION.3 CURLOPT_STDERR.3 CURLOPT_STREAM_DEPENDS.3 CURLOPT_STREAM_DEPENDS_E.3 CURLOPT_STREAM_WEIGHT.3 CURLOPT_SUPPRESS_CONNECT_HEADERS.3 CURLOPT_TCP_FASTOPEN.3 CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE.3 CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPIDLE.3 CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPINTVL.3 CURLOPT_TCP_NODELAY.3 CURLOPT_TELNETOPTIONS.3 CURLOPT_TFTP_BLKSIZE.3 CURLOPT_TFTP_NO_OPTIONS.3 CURLOPT_TIMECONDITION.3 CURLOPT_TIMEOUT.3 CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS.3 CURLOPT_TIMEVALUE.3 CURLOPT_TIMEVALUE_LARGE.3 CURLOPT_TLS13_CIPHERS.3 '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/share/man/man3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 CURLOPT_TLSAUTH_PASSWORD.3 CURLOPT_TLSAUTH_TYPE.3 CURLOPT_TLSAUTH_USERNAME.3 CURLOPT_TRAILERDATA.3 CURLOPT_TRAILERFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_TRANSFER_ENCODING.3 CURLOPT_TRANSFERTEXT.3 CURLOPT_UNIX_SOCKET_PATH.3 CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH.3 CURLOPT_UPKEEP_INTERVAL_MS.3 CURLOPT_UPLOAD.3 CURLOPT_UPLOAD_BUFFERSIZE.3 CURLOPT_URL.3 CURLOPT_USE_SSL.3 CURLOPT_USERAGENT.3 CURLOPT_USERNAME.3 CURLOPT_USERPWD.3 CURLOPT_VERBOSE.3 CURLOPT_WILDCARDMATCH.3 CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.3 CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_WS_OPTIONS.3 CURLOPT_XFERINFODATA.3 CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_XOAUTH2_BEARER.3 CURLSHOPT_LOCKFUNC.3 CURLSHOPT_SHARE.3 CURLSHOPT_UNLOCKFUNC.3 CURLSHOPT_UNSHARE.3 CURLSHOPT_USERDATA.3 '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/share/man/man3'
make[6]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 ../.././install-sh -c -d '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/share/aclocal'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libcurl.m4 '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/share/aclocal'
 ../.././install-sh -c -d '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/share/man/man3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 curl_easy_cleanup.3 curl_easy_duphandle.3 curl_easy_escape.3 curl_easy_getinfo.3 curl_easy_header.3 curl_easy_init.3 curl_easy_nextheader.3 curl_easy_option_by_id.3 curl_easy_option_by_name.3 curl_easy_option_next.3 curl_easy_pause.3 curl_easy_perform.3 curl_easy_recv.3 curl_easy_reset.3 curl_easy_send.3 curl_easy_setopt.3 curl_easy_strerror.3 curl_easy_unescape.3 curl_easy_upkeep.3 curl_escape.3 curl_formadd.3 curl_formfree.3 curl_formget.3 curl_free.3 curl_getdate.3 curl_getenv.3 curl_global_cleanup.3 curl_global_init.3 curl_global_init_mem.3 curl_global_sslset.3 curl_mime_addpart.3 curl_mime_data.3 curl_mime_data_cb.3 curl_mime_encoder.3 curl_mime_filedata.3 curl_mime_filename.3 curl_mime_free.3 curl_mime_headers.3 curl_mime_init.3 curl_mime_name.3 '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/share/man/man3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 curl_mime_subparts.3 curl_mime_type.3 curl_mprintf.3 curl_multi_add_handle.3 curl_multi_assign.3 curl_multi_cleanup.3 curl_multi_fdset.3 curl_multi_info_read.3 curl_multi_init.3 curl_multi_perform.3 curl_multi_poll.3 curl_multi_remove_handle.3 curl_multi_setopt.3 curl_multi_socket.3 curl_multi_socket_action.3 curl_multi_socket_all.3 curl_multi_strerror.3 curl_multi_timeout.3 curl_multi_wakeup.3 curl_multi_wait.3 curl_share_cleanup.3 curl_share_init.3 curl_share_setopt.3 curl_share_strerror.3 curl_slist_append.3 curl_slist_free_all.3 curl_strequal.3 curl_strnequal.3 curl_unescape.3 curl_url.3 curl_url_cleanup.3 curl_url_dup.3 curl_url_get.3 curl_url_set.3 curl_url_strerror.3 curl_version.3 curl_version_info.3 curl_ws_meta.3 curl_ws_recv.3 curl_ws_send.3 '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/share/man/man3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libcurl-easy.3 libcurl-env.3 libcurl-errors.3 libcurl-multi.3 libcurl-security.3 libcurl-share.3 libcurl-symbols.3 libcurl-thread.3 libcurl-tutorial.3 libcurl-url.3 libcurl.3 '/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out1/share/man/man3'
foo@bcd074b280e3 curl %
```

Comment: have you considered using `clang` instead of `gcc` ?

Comment: @RARE i have to debug my application that uses curl using gcc only. I should be able to build curl using clang and still debug my application correct. Btw any specific reason you are recommending clang over gcc, just curious

Comment: btw tried with clang as well , same result, i just did CC=Clang, before configuring

Comment: well to provide more context i am passing the curl to my application like below
`-DCURL_LIBRARY=/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out2/lib/curl.so
-DCURL_INCLUDE_DIR=/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out2/include/curl`

one of the module of my application is giving me this error 
`make[3]: *** No rule to make target /Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out2/lib/libcurl.so', needed by UtilsCommon/libUtilsCommon.dylib'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** [UtilsCommon/CMakeFiles/UtilsCommon.dir/all] Error 2`

Comment: Change to: `-DCURL_LIBRARY=/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out2/lib/libcurl.dylib` (or similiar)

Comment: @bourne : `clang`, or more generally, the `LLVM` framework, covers fewer languages, but that also means it has far less legacy baggage to lug around  - 15 years to be exact - since most of the gap involve really old languages and systems architectures that hardly anyone needs anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Shared object in AppleTalk is called *dylib.* So you only have to change this:

```
-   -DCURL_LIBRARY=/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out2/lib/curl.so
+   -DCURL_LIBRARY=/Users/foo/Workspace/curl2.0/out2/lib/libcurl.dylib
```